# nth-child selector not working(?) in css

Tags: html, css

So i want to use the nth-child selector to make the first paragraph red. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p:nth-child(1) {
background: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>I want this paragraph to be red.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But the result is 0 paragraphs with red color... I dont understand what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @Agglos Sfakianos see my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element like this:

```
   p:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

but if you are going to have more paragraphs you should put it inside a div and make this:

```
<div class="paragraphs">
<p>paragraph1</p>
<p>paragraph2</p>
<p>paragraph3</p>
<p>paragraph4</p>
</div>
```

and use this:

```
.paragraphs p:first-child {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use :first-of-type selector.

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p:first-of-type {
background: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>I want this paragraph to be red.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes but mostly the question was why the above code that i wrote is not working.. i want to fully understand the nth-child selector thats all. thanks for the answer anyways

Comment: In this case your code wasn't working because you were trying to apply the rule to a "p" tag which was the first child in its parent. Your p was the second child in its parent, because the first was the H1. 
p:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
Would work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Here `<p>` is not first element so `nth-child(1)` will not work you have to define type for this

```
p:first-of-type {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

**OR**

You can define it as second element

```
p:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

> If applying css for first child then use `first-child` instead of `nth-child(1)`